# Allow non-programmers to build sites

Tags: forms

Is there a way to allow a user who is not a developer to enter the text and slideshow images for a Lead Generator page without going through all of the Drupal screens? I need to allow our marketing department to create Lead Gen pages, which they do frequently. Every page uses the same theme and settings. The only thing that changes is the content (images and text).

Basically, I need a simplified UI where the user can enter the variable content, but other settings (like page visibility and slideshow settings) use our defaults.

Can I either create a new data entry screen(s) or filter/restrict/reorganize the existing screen(s) for this?

Comment: Is "Lead Generator" a specific content type then?

Comment: Create a new role for them and assign that to marketing user accounts. Then go to permissions and only give them access to what they need.